# Український відповідник "referral"?

Tags: переклад, from-english, запозичені-слова, неологізми

Стаття у Вікіпедії зазначає, що

> [Реферал](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB) (або реферал, від англ. referral — «напрям») — учасник партнерської програми, зареєстрований за рекомендацією іншого учасника. Така схема маркетингу широко поширена в інтернеті і передбачає реєстрацію на сайтах, що надають якісь послуги. У цьому випадку рекомендація супроводжується «реферальним посиланням», що містить інформацію про обліковий запис учасника, який отримає винагороду за залучення новачків.

Розділ "Посилання" цієї ж статті свідчить, що звісно ж вживається переважно звичайна транслітерація.

Про це ж свідчить і відповідний [пошук в Інтернеті](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%D0%A0%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB&t=hf&ia=web). Спостерігається інколи навіть використання і в англійському написанні (оригінальному, тобто латиницею).

До [Офіційного сайту Української мови](https://ukrainskamova.com/search/?q=%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB&t=0), [Онлайн Словника іншомовних слів](http://www.jnsm.com.ua), [Загального народного англійсько-українського словника](https://e2u.org.ua), [Словника Укрліт.ORG](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk) та
[Вільного тлумачного словника (Новітній онлайновий словник української мови (2013—2018))](http://sum.in.ua/f/) це слово звісно "ще не вспіло дійти".

Народний Словотвір взагалі [пропонує](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/referal) щось "страшне та невеселе", накшталт:

> *рекрут* або *покличник*

Тож чи існує якийсь варіант українського слова - відповідника, зафіксований хоча б у одному із сучасних виданих словників?